# element from a list wrapped as option

Tags: scala, collections

Is there a better/shorter/more concise way to write this?

```
def elementOrNone[T](values: List[T], index: Int): Option[T] =
   values match { 
    case Nil => None
    case _ => Some(values(index))
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes

```
val xs = List(1,2,3)
scala> xs.lift(1)
//res2: Option[Int] = Some(2)

scala> xs.lift(10)
//res3: Option[Int] = None

scala> val ys = List.empty[Int]
// ys: List[Int] = List()

scala> ys.lift(0)
// res1: Option[Int] = None
```

(But unlike your code, lift wont throw java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException if you're asking for element with index larger than collection size -- I don't know whether it is good or bad for you).

Comment: It's worth noting that this works because `List[A]` has `PartialFunction[Int, A]` as one of its supertypes, and any partial function can be lifted to a total function with an `Option`-wrapped result.

Comment: It's also worth noting that while `xs.lift(1)` may look like an innocent method call, it actually creates a function instance everytime and then calls it's apply method.

Answer (score 0):

Here list has a lift method. If you ever need to do something very similar with other API you can write the lift method yourself. I've seen an example lifting getConnection from the JDBC driver so it can be used safely.